# Using a random operator many variables

Tags: java, random, operator-keyword

I want to add a random operators so I can randomly add/subtract/multiply/divide multiple variables. The code below doesn't work. I think it's because the randomly generated operator is a char which actually has a value so it's added rather than used as an operator. Anyway I'm new at this and any help would be great thanks!

```
class ClassA{
public static void main(String[] args){
    ClassB x = new ClassB();

    int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4;
    int answer;

    //Trying to achieve
    //answer = a (+,-,*,/) b (+,-,*,/) c (+,-,*,/) d
    //i.e
    answer = a+x.randomOperator()+b+x.randomOperator()+c+x.randomOperator()+d;

    System.out.println("answer="+answer);

}
}
```

I generate the random operator sign in a different class.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ClassB{
public char randomOperator(){
    Random rv = new Random();
    int apples = rv.nextInt(3);
    char operator;

    switch (apples)
    {
        case 1:
            operator = '+';
            break;
        case 2:
            operator = '-';
            break;
        case 3:
            operator = '*';
            break;
        default:
            operator = '/';
            break;
    }
    return operator;
}
}
```

I also think I should add I'm trying to do this for multiple numbers and while two numbers is fine the more numbers I add it gets vastly more complex so I cannot really write out every combination. Maybe this just cannot be done but I thought I'd ask! thanks!

Comment: This cannot be done. You can't have dynamic class code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do since `'+'` is just a `char` and doesn't have any other meaning, except the value itself. It can't be translated dynamically into code.

The simpler solution that comes into my mind is something like:

```
interface Operation {
  int eval(int a, int b);
}

class Addition {
  int eval(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}

class Subtraction {
  int eval(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
}

...

Operation[] operations = new Operation[]{new Addition(), new Subtraction(), ..};

int executeRandom(int a, int b) {
  return operations[random.nextInt(operations.length)].eval(a,b);
}
```

Comment: A more OOP version of my answer. Nice :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do something like:

```
Random randomInteger = new Random();
switch(randomInteger.Next(0, 4)) // Grab a random integer between [0, 4)
{
    case 0: // Add
        return a + b;
    case 1: // Subtract
        return a - b;
    case 2: // Multiply
        return a * b;
    case 3: // Divide
        return a / b;
}
```

rather than what you're doing currently.

Comment: I can see this but when I'll be using 6 variables the number of combinations to add/subtract/multiply/divide them is enormous and I was hoping for a quicker way of doing it. I think without division there are about 160 combinations, with division it gets way bigger!  Thanks for your response though!

Comment: @Dodo: he's not using the `randomInteger` to choose which operation of the sequence but which specific operation apply for any pair of operands. The number of chained variables doesn't matter.

Comment: Check out Jack's answer for something much more robust than mine. My code is more suited for a quick one-off.

Comment: I think I get it now! thanks for you help Jack & David!